# hg-git can pull from forked repo, but not original repo

Tags: mercurial, github, tortoisehg, hg-git

I'm using TortoiseHg with the hg-git Mercurial plugin to interact with Github without using Git at all, only Hg.  On Github, I forked the [pandas repo](https://github.com/pydata/pandas).  I successfully cloned my fork to my computer.  I want to add the original pandas repo as a URL in Hg, so I can pull changes from that repo and integrate them with whatever changes I make myself.  I added the original pandas repo in the URLs in TortoiseHg under the name "upstream".

However, if I try to pull from that original upstream repo, Hg hangs for a long time and then eventually issues a "504 - Gateway timeout" error.  If I directly clone the pandas repo (instead of cloning my fork of it), I can pull from it fine.

The strange thing is that this doesn't seem to happen with all repos.  I did the same process (fork, clone the fork, then try to pull from the original) with the [matplotlib repo](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib), and it seems to pull from the original repo just fine.

Even stranger, if I clone the original repo, and then add my fork as an extra URL, I can pull from both.  So somehow the URL as set during the original clone is okay, but setting the same URL manually as a source doesn't work.

This seems to indicate that the problem is with the pandas repo specifically.  Is this possible?  Is there some setting on Github that could be affecting my ability to pull from that repo?  What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Is there a proxy server involved?  If so, it's likely that the cause is that the timeout on the proxy server is too low.

Comment: @davidmc24: I'm not using a proxy server.  Also, I don't see how that could explain that it works with one repo and not another, or that I can pull from the exact same URL if I clone the original repo directly.

Comment: My guess of a proxy server was based on the error code, which seems to usually be related to a proxy of some form.  If there were a proxy involved, the differences between cloning and pulling could possibly be explained by minor differences in the network calls being made either falling within the timeout or not.  Likewise, the difference in behavior between this repo and others might be explainable due to differences in size or object composition.

Answer (score 2):

I repeated the process with `hg-git` via the command line and couldn't replicate the problem. So there are a few possibilities:

1. There's either an issue with (your) TortoiseHG (config).
2. You've made a typo of some type when entering the URL into TortoiseHG.
3. There's a weird corner case in `hg-git`.
4. Something is causing trouble in your `hgrc` -- either your global one (hidden in your home directory) or your repository specific one (found in `.hg/hgrc`).

If you provide your `hgrc` files as a Github Gist (anonymizing them as need be), that might provide some insight.

In the meantime, one solution is to do the git stuff by hand and then force an update:

```
cd path/to/hg/repo
git fetch https://github.com/pydata/pandas.git # equal to hg pull, 
hg gimport # pulls the changesets from the hidden git repo into the mercurial repo
```

If this works, then there's probably something wrong with the saved URL.

You still have to worry about merging and rebasing and whatnot, but you can do that within Mercurial. The hidden git repo will be automatically when you do a push to a git remote, or you can force it to update via `hg gexport`.